# automate file text edits

Tags: automator, script, text-editor, html, websites

I have an online website that I'd like to move to a new URL.
Therefore I need to edit all website html files (100+ files) to update the URL links inside each file of this website.

I'm thinking of making an off-line copy of the website files to edit.

Is it possibile to use Automator OS X to
- open each file in the website file folder
- search inside the file content for a specific URL link (say "www.website.com") and change it to the new URL (say "www.website.com/old")?

Else, do I need to rely on a text editor + Automator to make this process?

Or, can it be done using a UNIX script that you run in the Terminal ?

Thanks for any advice on how to perform this process!

Comment: You can use `sed` in Terminal, but for a specific answer we would need to see an excerpt of one of the web pages showing the old and the new URL.

Comment: I did something similar a while back but did it in BBEdit as it can find/replace across multiple files. In case you are interested in commercial ($) options.

Comment: Did any of the solutions below help you?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all files are in the same folder:

```
mkdir new
for i in *.html; do
    sed 's|website.com|website.com/old|g' "$i" > "new/$i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're commonly editing website file contents you should invest in an editor.

### [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

Drop the website onto the icon and it will build the project:

[image]

run <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and enter the replacement:

[image]

Click the `Replace` button and verify the `Replace`:

[image]

It will open and change all the files:

[image]

---

### [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)

Is an excellent and robust application I primarily use to edit code.  Drag and drop the folder onto BBEdit and go to `File -> Save Project` and it will create a file named `foobar.bbprojectd`:

[image]

run <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and select the project with the replacement parameters:

[image]

It will prompt you after clicking `Replace All`:

[image]

If you are unsure on your changes select `Leave Open` because if you select `Save to disk` it is very hard to revert back.

---

### Perl

There is already a `sed` solution but you could also do the same with Perl:

```
# !/bin/bash

DIR="/Users/vader/desktop/test"
NEW="$DIR/new"

if [ ! -e "$DIR/new" ]; then 
    mkdir -p new
    echo "made folder new"
else
    echo "folder exists"
fi

for htmlfile in $(ls "$DIR"/*.html); do
    TEMPFILE="$htmlfile.$$"
    htmlbase=$(basename $htmlfile)
    echo "Working on "$htmlbase
    perl -pe 's|www.website.com|www.website.com\/old|g' "$htmlfile" > $TEMPFILE && mv $TEMPFILE "$NEW/$htmlbase"
done
```

There are other editors out there but these are the two I primarily use.  You could also do this in pure AppleScript but you haven't shown any code and mentioned terminal so I made the above in Perl.